# Replacing python with_statement by setUp and tearDown in Unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest, with-statement

In a test suite I have some code organized as below, context is some persistent object that is deleted when exiting the `with` block:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_action1(self):
        with create_context() as context:
            context.prepare_context()
            context.action1()
            self.assertTrue(context.check1())
            
    def test_action2(self):
        with create_context() as context:
            context.prepare_context()
            context.action2()
            self.assertTrue(context.check2())
```

It's obvious that code has some repetition of setup boilerplate in both tests, hence I would like to use setUp() and tearDown() methods to factorize that boilerplate.

But I don't know how to extract the with_statement. What I came up with is something like this:

```
class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.context = create_context()
        self.context.prepare_context()

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.context()

    def test_action1(self):
        self.context.action1()
        self.assertTrue(self.context.check1())
            
    def test_action2(self):
        self.context.action2()
        self.assertTrue(self.context.check2())
```

But I believe this is not really equivalent when test fails, also having to put an explicit delete in tearDown() doesn't feel right.

What is the correct way to change my with_statement code to setUp() and tearDown() style ?

Comment: `def Test(TestCase):` is it `def` or `class` ?

Comment: @TomWojcik: `class`, it is pseudocode, the actual code is much more complicated. I will fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about the setUp() and tearDown(), but the methods defined in context managers `__enter__` and `__exit__` sound like they do what you want them to do (just with different names):

```
class ContextTester():
    def __enter__(self):
        self.context = create_context()
        self.context.prepare_context()
        return self.context

    def __exit(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.context.close()

def Test(TestCase):
    def test_action1(self):
        with ContextTester() as context:
            context.action1()
            self.assertTrue(context.check1())
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought of that, but that means moving all the test boilerplate code to context management and completely stop using the old setUp()/tearDown(). It could be the way to go.

Comment: well i believe that's kind of the intention of context managers. they allow you to factor out repetitive setup/teardown code

Comment: Yes, but in my case that means wrapping existing context manager in user defined context manager. I could also have to work with several `with` contexts. It could get complicated quite fast. Also for cleaning my existing context, I should probably provide it the parameters passed to `__exit__`, like explicitely calling `self.context.__exit__()` rather than calling `close()`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) for that.

> A context manager that is designed to make it easy to programmatically combine other context managers and cleanup functions, especially those that are optional or otherwise driven by input data.

```
import contextlib
from unittest import TestCase


class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        stack = contextlib.ExitStack()
        self.context = stack.enter_context(create_context())  # create_context is your context manager
        self.addCleanup(stack.close)

    def test_action1(self):
        self.context.prepare_context()
        self.context.action1()
        self.assertTrue(self.context.check1())
```

or if you want to have some control over the teardown or use multiple context managers this will be better

```
import contextlib
from unittest import TestCase


class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            self.context = stack.enter_context(create_context())  # create_context is your context manager
            self._resource_stack = stack.pop_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        self._resource_stack.close()

    def test_action1(self):
        self.context.prepare_context()
        self.context.action1()
        self.assertTrue(self.context.check1())
```